# How to use a texture to distort only the edges of a brush in texture paint?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, brushes

As the title says I'd like to distort the edges of my brush without having the actual inner color of my brush be affected. How do I do this?

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm trying to do this with procedural noise.

Comment: Without a picture of what you mean, I am just guessing but have you looked at using a Brush Mask texture instead of using a Brush texture? You can set it to Rake and Random and use Pressure Masking to Ramp and also turn on Accumulate in the advanced tab - that will get you some solid paint in the middle of your dabs but allow you to break up the edges pretty well.